# How to use JavaScript onload function to display a message

Tags: javascript, html, popup, onload

I am approaching for the first time in JavaScript and I am trying to implement the *onload* function to show a message every time the page of my site is loaded. Can you help me by showing me some lines of code?

Comment: We might need you to be a little more specific on what do you mean by "your site". Is it running in IIS? Something else? Is there all there is regarding the code? Can you check the code by inspecting the elements on the page to make sure they are the same?

Comment: Your code works well here. This is not surprising. The problem is in the rest of the code. Is it possible to give url to the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never use body onload. It is very simple for other scripts to overwrite.

Instead use addEventListener which will ADD your function to the load and cannot be overwritten

```html
<html>
<header>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
</header>
<script>
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    alert("Hey!");
  })
</script>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

That said, it is very weird that an alert was dismissed since it is system modal. Are you sure you use alert?

Comment: I was told to implement the onload function in the body of my page, which is part of a university project, so I wrote it like this. I tried your code but it always gives me the same problem. Why do you think alert is not good? What could be an alternative? Unfortunately JavaScript is new to me, so any advice is welcome

Comment: I did not say alert is not good, I am saying it is really weird it is dismissed. Perhaps You are missing to tell us something about the system you are writing code on? Like not a normal text editor and browser?